# Access token from WP8 not working on WebApi 2 endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have a basic SPA template with WebApi 2 backend that uses Microsoft account as external login provider. I also have a WP8 client in which users can login with their Microsoft account, both the SPA and WP8 client use ClientId so a users with same email address get the same identifiers in both clients (the ProviderKeys stored at the db match the id's for the same users when they log in on the phone).

When a user has logged in through the browser I can get their access_token and authenticate further requests they make against the api through the bearer token, this works well, returning 200 every time. On the WP8 client it doesnt work however, this is how I get the token:

```
LiveAuthClient Auth = new LiveAuthClient("0000000041422E16");
//some code removed
LiveConnectClient connect = new LiveConnectClient(Auth.Session);
string access_token = connect.Session.AccessToken;
//use token to send a http request to an authorized endpoint
```

I've used Fiddler to test the access token and the WebApi always return 401, what am I doing wrong here? Aren't the tokens sent back by the Live SDK client valid for authentication on the WebApi endpoints?

Comment: You are getting token properly, but not able to make next service requests? If yes, then please share some code how you are trying to fetch it after getting token.

Comment: There isn't much code after this point because I create a GET request in Fiddler to a protected endpoint with that token set as the Authorization header, I'm confident i got this part right because it works when I use the token received from the web browser, it doesn't however work for the token received from the WP8 client.